# Google Analytics Pod installs too many dependencies

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, cocoapods, google-analytics-api

I've just included the Google Analytics Pod as described in [their iOS developer guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/) with:

```
pod 'Google/Analytics'
```

When running

```
pod install
```

it installs the following dependencies:

```
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (3.2.0)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.6)
Installing Google (3.0.3)
Installing GoogleAnalytics (3.14.0)
Installing GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.1)
Installing GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.1)
Installing GoogleUtilities (1.3.1)
```

Since I don't use Firebase, I would like to get rid of the `FirebaseAnalytics` and `FirebaseInstanceID` (as well as all pods that are not needed by the framework itself).

Installing unused dependencies only bloats up my app size. I would like to only **install the absolute minimum amount of pods to get GoogleAnalytics running**.

Any ideas on how to kick the unused Pods out?

Comment: I am also facing same issue, Can any one help us to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41928235/376683), you can use:

```rb
pod 'GoogleAnalytics'
```

…to avoid installing the dependencies. Note that you'll need to change your Objective-C imports in your bridging header file; I needed at least:

```c
#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAI.h>
#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAIFields.h>
#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAIDictionaryBuilder.h>
```