# How can I integrate only Google Analytics for iOS without Firebase, using Cocoapods?

Tags: ios, google-analytics, cocoapods

As of now I integrated using the following:

```
pod 'Google/Analytics'
```

But I am getting so many logs about FireBase.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Analytics with Firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659880/google-analytics-with-firebase)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43932771/376683